# Update nginx on Amazon linux (CentOs)

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to update nginx on a amazon linux instance which I read is compatible with centos repos.On their site there is a [little guide to upgrade the repo](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html). However I'm not sure how to translate it from centos to amazon linux.

> To set up the yum repository for RHEL/CentOS, create the file named
> `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo` with the following contents:
>
> ```
> [nginx] 
> name=nginx repo
> baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/OS/OSRELEASE/$basearch/ 
> gpgcheck=0
> enabled=1
> ```
>
> Replace “OS” with “rhel” or “centos”, depending on the
> distribution used, and “OSRELEASE” with “5”, “6”, or “7”, for 5.x,
> 6.x, or 7.x versions, respectively.

What should I put for osrelease ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what version of CentOS you are using, then run this command:

```
rpm --query centos-release
```

You will get output like this: `centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64`

So obviously from the output I can tell I have CentOS 7.2.
In my case, `baseurl` will look like this:

```
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/$basearch/
```

Comment: it says package centos-release is not installed . I believe amazon linux is a modified version of centos and the repository works for them too

Comment: @Ced then you can try use the repo for CentOS 7 or 6, I don't know how the amazon linux works.

Comment: try `uname -a` to get the version of your system